# Unable to mock out function within a class that gets stimulated using event emitter in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have 2 files.

listener.js:

```
'use strict';    
var events = require('./g-events');    
function start() {
  console.log('starting');
}

events.on(events.ACTIVITY_EVENT, function() {
  console.log('i am in here');
  start();
});

// Public functions
module.exports = {
  start: start
};
```

with events defined as :

```
'use strict';
var EventEmitter2 = require('eventemitter2').EventEmitter2;

var m = new EventEmitter2({
  newListener: false,
  maxListeners: 20
});
m.ACTIVITY_EVENT = 'activityEvent';
module.exports = m;
```

Created a test class that tests the endpoint.

```
var listener = require('../listener');
var events = require('../g-events');    

describe('test listener', function() {
  listener.start = function() {
    console.log('fake start');
  };
  it('test listener', function() {
    events.emit(events.ACTIVITY_EVENT);
  });
});
```

When the test runs, the output is 'i am in here' and then 'starting'.
Why isn't it properly overriding the start function defined in my test?

Comment: Inside your test function `listener.start` refers to the `module.exports` object from `listerner.js`, modifying it will just modify the object property; not the `start()` function in `listener.js`

Comment: What's the proper way to stub out the start method?

My end goal is stubbing it out using sinon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even using sinon to stub out the method, it still evaluated the original method.

I ended up stumbling upon rewire https://github.com/jhnns/rewire to do what I wanted, though I'm not entirely sure why sinon wasn't able to stub out an exported method.